# Limit size of directory in a specific disk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, directory, external-hdd, ext4

In my Kubuntu 16.10 system, I have a directory which is continuously receiving data from Internet. Right now it has almost 50GB and it will get possibly something like 130GB.

Is there any way to limit the amount of data stored in this directory to something like 65GB, and make the rest of the data be stored in another directory in an external drive? I mean, after the last byte in the current directory, the next one be stored in the new directory.

Also, this new directory will have a limit too, and when this one is reached, the data flow is redirected to another directory, in another external drive.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I think not. quotas (start with `man quota`) seem to be for filesystems. You will have to fix whatever programs are sending/receiving data.

Comment: Is your problem a case of free available space on any given disk, or something else? LVM might solve some of your needs, but it would require re-initializing all concerned disks to lvm format. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm.

Comment: Is it a single file growing to 65GB and then 130GB or is it a group of files?

Answer (score 1):

Of the ways to make filesystems spread out over disks (RAID, LVM, btrfs, ZFS, etc.), they make entire filesystems (or partitions, in case of RAID, LVM) spread out over disks, and you can't reliably dictate what gets written where. Of the ways to make directories on two filesystems appear as one (overlays), only one can be used for writing. So, I'd say there's no way to do what you ask.

You can set a limit to a directory (see [How to set a file size limit for a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/q/841282/158442)), but I don't think make it overflow elsewhere, unless the application supports it. The simplest way I can think if is to detect when the disk is full and restart the process while pointing it to the new disk.