# Quota on a directory

Tags: server, quota

I want a User not to be able to occupy more than 1 megabyte in the /home directory of the server and, if so, I want to send him a short message.

I have found `fallocate - l 0.001G` but it doesn't works on a directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a file size limit for a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841282/how-to-set-a-file-size-limit-for-a-directory)

Comment: i don't understand the answer, i am new to linux