# Set a size limit in a directory and utilize the unused space

Tags: files, filesystem

I want to set a size limit in a directory.
There is an answer already in this question,
https://askubuntu.com/a/841306/1644693

But this example creates 2Gb file, I want to utilize the unused space if the directory is not fully used.

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the answer there?  It says it right in the first two sentences:  "Usual filesystem quota on ext4 is per-user/group, not per-directory. ZFS can sort-of set a directory quota, by creating a filesystem of a fixed size off a ZFS volume."

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't remember so I read it again, but I am still not sure how I can do this. if you know already will you please explain to me? if possible I want to do this on ext4 partition. thanks.

Comment: The comment is that is cannot be done per directory on ext4.  It is per user/group for quotas.